# Is the JSON response already stringfied?

Tags: javascript, json

The JSON response we got from the server is already stringfied or we need to Stringfy it and then parse.

Comment: You json string looks ok for me... What exactly did you expected to be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ready to use. Just eval it or use some sane parsing function (i.e. jQuery.parseJSON)

Answer (score 0):

The results is already in JSON. Assuming that your using jQuery AJAX, you can use the results

```
$.ajax(
 ...
 success = function(json) {
   // you can then access the data like
   json.ScheduleCareProviderScheduledPatientsGetResult .. // etc
 }
});
```

Comment: This only works if (a) the content type is set correctly (`application/json` afaik) or (b) the `dataType` is set to `json`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be JSON as long as the return content type is set to application/JSON.

Comment: Any text that is in JSON format is JSON, regardless of the content type. You probably meant that if the content type is set correctly, it is often automatically parsed to JavaScript objects...